# GNU Octave/Matlab: How to get the index of the three biggest values in an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, max

Let's say I have an array `A = [ 41 13 22 18 32]`
How can I get the indexes of the three greatest values?

In this example I expect to get 1,5,3 (indexes of 41,32,22).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/30693-find-the-3-maximum-elements-and-their-index) documentation:

```
A = [ 41 13 22 18 32];
[val idx]=sort(A,'descend');
top3_idx=idx(1:3)
```

It works in [Octave online](https://octave-online.net/)

Comment: Theoretically that should do it, you are right.. But doesn't seem to do anything in Octave... "The 'maxk' function is not yet implemented in Octave." :/

Comment: this works in octave online:
`A = [ 41 13 22 18 32];
[x idx]=sort(A,'descend');
top3_idx=idx(1:3)`

Comment: Actually maxk returns values, not indices, sorry, I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Meanwhile, I found another maybe convoluted solution: `A = [ 41 13 22 18 32]
B = flipud(sortrows(reshape([ A ; (1:length(A)) ], 2, []).')) max1 = B(1,2)
max2 = B(2,2)
max3 = B(3,2)`